# Using LARGE with AVERAGEIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to combine AVERAGEIFS and LARGE but am unable to generate the required result. From the example:

```
WOLF    10
TIGER   5
TIGER   6
WOLF    9
TIGER   7
TIGER   7
WOLF    9
TIGER   8
TIGER   1
WOLF    7
```

I want the average for `WOLF` of its three highest values. `WOLF` has values `10`, `9`, `9` and `7` so the top three would be `10`, `9`, `9` then the average should be `9.33`.

How I should run it with AVERAGEIFS and LARGE, or maybe other functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an array formula, so confirm with Control-Shift-Enter:

```
=AVERAGE(LARGE(IF(A1:A10="wolf",B1:B10),{1;2;3}))
```

Adjust the two ranges to meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks :) this sure help.